# Force equal width columns in CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't think what I'm trying to do is possible.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make all the `.item`s to take up **the maximum, identical horizontal space** that is (about) 33% in the 1st one, 50% in the second one, and 100% in the last?

The idea here is to **not set the size** of the `.item`s (and avoiding setting `id`s to elements) for maximum flexibility and minimum error surface. If this is impossible with Flexbox, but doable using another strategy, what would it be?

Comment: But what's your current CSS? `impossible with FlexBox but doable using another strategy` --> it's usually the other way around :)

Comment: `flex:1` to all element ! this is the very basic thing you learn from a Flex tuto ...

Comment: flex is just shorthand, flex-basis it the most accurate one

Comment: @pkolawa whataver, there is a ton of method to this with flexbox and i provided one

Comment: Currently, `flex: 1` distributes the randomly numbered items OK, but somehow they are *not* the same width

Comment: with you actual HTML, they will be the same size

Comment: Guys, I'm confused ; You are basically all right ; What happened is that there was a `white-space: nowrap` in one of the items, causing it to take half the horiz. space of its siblings. 1+ to all of you, and thanks for your patience :/

Answer (score 23):

You can just set `width: 100%;` to the `.item` (remove margins if you want them to take up 100% space):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.item {
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Set `flex-grow: 1;` on your items.

```css
.row {
  height : 30px;
  border : blue dashed 1px;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
   border : green solid 2px;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-grow` will eventually cause varying widths if the contents if the `divs` vary.
The most appropriate method is using `width:100%;`.